# MySQL Connector in Java

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

So I have this Java project I need to edit on my PC. So it gives me an error saying:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Project 'Pecarosi' is missing
>   required library: 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector.J
>   5.1\mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar'  Pecarosi        Build path  Build Path Problem

So , right , it says that I miss mysql-connector-java-5.1.**38**-bin.jar which is true but I do have mysql-connector-java-5.1.**40**-bin.jar. How do I change it inside the project to read the one that I have?

I'm kinda new to Java so don't judge.

P.S. I'm using Eclipse Mars.2 :)

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse, Go to Package Explorer, Right click on Project, Go to Build Path and then Configure Build Path. You'll see old jar name which is missing. Remove that entry of missing jar and add the new jar you have by clicking on "Add External JARs". Press Ok and all. Build the project if not set to 'Build Automatically' in Project menu. That's it. You are good to go!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. :)

Comment: @HushenSavani - if this worked for you, please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer BackSlash. I think @Tuhoaminen can accept my answer.